# Copy a large directory to the SAMBA shared directory

Tags: windows, performance, samba, smb, cifs

## description

When I try to create more than 100,000 files in the SAMBA shared dir, the smbd cpu usage increases as the number of files increases and performance degrades. I look at the smbd log, before the creation of each document will receive from the client SMB2_FIND request, the request parameters in_file_name = "*", used to obtain the entire directory of information. That is to say that each file needs to create a whole directory of information, with the increase in the number of sub-files, performance significantly decreased. I would like to ask is whether the SMB protocol to consider the use of a large number of documents under the directory scene, smbd there is no way to optimize, or modify the configuration can improve performance?

## test environment

- client: windows8
- server: centos7.1
- smbd version:

  ```
  [root@localhost samba]# ps aux | grep smbd
  root      3378  0.0  0.3 386040  5800 ?        Ss   20:43   0:00            /usr/sbin/smbd
  root      3380  0.0  0.1 386040  3108 ?        S    20:43   0:00 /usr/sbin/smbd
  root      3385  0.0  0.3 390600  7004 ?        S    20:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/smbd
  root      3504  0.0  0.0 112648   976 pts/0    R+   21:09   0:00 grep --  color=auto smbd
  [root@localhost samba]# /usr/sbin/smbd --version
  Version 4.2.10
  ```

## test procedure

- modify smb.conf

  ```
  [root@localhost samba]# testparm -s -c
  Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
  rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
  Processing section "[1111]"
  Loaded services file OK.
  Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
  [global]
  workgroup = MYGROUP
  server string = Samba Server Version %v
  security = USER
  log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
  max log size = 900000000
  server max protocol = SMB2
  idmap config * : backend = tdb

  [1111]
  comment = share
  path = /tmp
  read only = No
  ```
- restart smbd service

  ```
  [root@localhost samba]# service smb restart
  Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart  smb.service
  ```
- map a directory to a network disk

[image]

- Write the test program

  ```
  var writewg sync.WaitGroup         
  var i uint64
  for i = 0; i < files; i++ {
      writewg.Add(1);
      ctx.sem <- true
      go func(index uint64) {
          if isdir {
              subdir := path + "/dir_" + strconv.FormatUint(index, 10)
              os.MkdirAll(subdir, 0777)
          } else {
              file := path + "/file_" + strconv.FormatUint(index, 10)
              f, err := os.OpenFile(file, os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND|os.O_RDWR, os.ModePerm|os.ModeTemporary)
              if err != nil {
                  fmt.Println("OpenFile ", file, " failed ", err );
              } else {
                  f.Write(ctx.data[0:])
                  f.Close()
              }
          }
          atomic.AddUint64(&ctx.task.Ops, 1)
          <- ctx.sem
          writewg.Add(-1)
      }(i)
  }
  writewg.Wait()
  ```
- run my test program

create 500 files

- View the log

  ```
  [root@localhost samba]# grep "smbd_dirptr_get_entry mask=.*file_0" log.xjl | wc -l
  500
  [root@localhost samba]# grep "SMB2_OP_FIND" log.xjl | wc -l
  1020
  ```